# Call for Common Practice Feedback

Tags: github-enterprise

my name is Benjamin Mach and I’m a student of computer science at the FAU Erlangen-Nürnberg. For my bachelor thesis, I want to prepare measurement software for collaboration within software organizations that collaborate (potentially over intra-organizational boundaries) using software forges. For the models we want to use, it is important that I collect data about the structure of the organizations.

I read about a strategy of resolving the missing hierarchy through delimiters. (e.g. maingroup-subgroup1-subgroupofsubgroup3) Is this common practice for you and if not, how do you handle this?

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,

Benjamin Mach

Comment: Sorry, but polls like this are not allowed here.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post on Stackoverflow and i wasn't of that. I just changed my question. It is now a single question. I would just like to get a best image of the overall direction i should work my implementation towards.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not much better: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. This question is way too broad.